# Can't put Theme on Burg boot/burg/themes, it said "Permission not Granted"

Tags: permissions, root, burg

How to get permission for all directory ?

Because every-time I want to put themes on that directory, it always said "`Permission not Granted`". I did research, but not help.

Comment: Have you tried using a root shell? `sudo -s`

Answer (score 1):

You need root permissions to do that.  Open a terminal and launch Nautilus as root:

```
sudo nautilus
```

or

```
gksu nautilus
```

enter your password and you're good to go.  Be carefull because root permissions can screw up your whole system!